# Reusing the same shortcut.js function to handle keyboard input

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I'm using [shortcut.js](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/) to handle keyboard input and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve my goal (currently most of the same code is copied and pasted).

For example, i have:

```
  shortcut.add("0",function() {
    points = -1;
    sec = 0;
  }); 

  shortcut.add("1",function() {
    points = 1;
    sec = 0;
  }); 

  shortcut.add("2",function() {
    points = 2;
    sec = 0;
  }); 

  shortcut.add("3",function() {
    points = 3;
    sec = 0;
  });
```

Ideally, I can generalize the function so that whatever key is entered is actually assigned to the points variable, *except* in the case where the user enters 0. In that case, the points variable is set to -1.

Any ideas on how to make this happen? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A loop with a closure should do the trick:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 9; ++i) {
    (function(i) {  // Capture current value of 'i' in this scope.
        shortcut.add(i.toString(), function() {
            points = i || -1;  // 'i' if 'i' is not 0, else -1.
            sec = 0;
        });
    })(i);
}
```

*Update following comment:* So why do we need a closure here? And what does the final `(i);` mean?

Basically, we need a closure because the anonymous functions passed to `shortcut.add()` will not be called right away, but some time in the future, after the loop has terminated. The functions capture `i` by reference, not by value, which means they will see the value of `i` that is current *at the time they run*, not *at the time they're defined*.

So, if we call `shortcut.add()` directly from the loop body, all the anonymous functions we pass will end up seeing the value of `i` that is current after the loop has terminated, which will always be the same (`10`).

Creating a new variable in each iteration looks like it could work, but doesn't:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 9; ++i) {
    var _i = i;  // Create new variable containing current value of 'i'.
    shortcut.add(i.toString(), function() {
        points = _i || -1;  // Won't work, '_i' is always 9.
        sec = 0;
    });
}
```

Since `for` loop bodies do not have their own scope in Javascript, `_i` ends up in function scope, the same as `i`, and will be captured the same way (its final value will be `9` instead of `10` because `++i` does not apply to it).

So, what we really need here is a new scope in each iteration. To achieve this, we can define a function inside the loop, and call it immediately, passing it the current value of `i`:

```
var newScope = function(i) {
    // Here, the value of 'i' will be the one current when 'newScope' is called
    // and will not change, even if 'i' is captured by other functions.
};
newScope(i);  // Call function with current value of 'i'.
```

Finally, we can do that without introducing the `newScope` name, by directly applying the call operator `()` to the function definition:

```
(function(i) {
    // Here, the value of 'i' will be the one current when this function is
    // called and will not change, even if 'i' is captured by other functions.
})(i);  // Call function with current value of 'i'.
```

I hope this appropriately answers your questions, feel free to leave further comments if it does not. For more information about closures, see [Closures on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Comment: wow, this worked beautifully! i don't quite understand exactly how it works as i am quite new to JS. can you explain the final "(i);" at the end? also, any pointers to helpful tutorials/docs on closures would be much appreciated! will use google too.

Comment: @tonic, fair point, I tried to provide a better explanation in my updated answer.

Comment: superb follow-up! incredibly helpful and well written. thanks so much for your help! i will also read up further and play around with more examples as well. cheers.